# How to make histogram from already aggregated data?

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to make a histogram of huge amount of data using highcharts.js .

The default chart.histogram like https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram does not meet my needs, because I want to aggregate the data myself using BigQuery.

So the input data would be `[[0, 123], [10, 1234], [20, 12345], ... , [90, 1234]]` .

Can I use bar chart as histogram by tweaking the options?

Or is there any easier way to make histogram from already aggregated data like above?

I think simply inputting the data into bar chart does not work as histgram, in terms of styling of the chart.

Comment: Of course - that's all a histogram is. Remove the space between columns ( `groupPadding: 0, pointPadding: 0` ), supply your binned data, and you have a histogram.

Comment: You've the answer here: https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=41377. Please follow this thread.

Answer (score 0):

*Can I use bar chart as histogram by tweaking the options?*

Sure! Columns accept data array like that, following the author comment the data must be separated :

```
var bigQueryData = [[0, 123], [10, 420], [20, 650], [30, 712], [40, 1020], [50, 1300], [60, 900], [70, 681], [80, 351], [90, 220]];

var xAxisCat = [],
    realData = [];

bigQueryData.forEach(data =>{
    xAxisCat.push( (data[0]).toString() );
    realData.push( data[1] );
});
...
xAxis:{
    title: { text: 'Histogram' },
    type:'category',
    categories: xAxisCat
},
...
series: [{
    name: 'custom Histogram',
    type: 'column',
    data: realData,
}]
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nx5c8Lr1/)

Comment: Thank you! But I want it to be styled like the demo of histogram. I mean, the scales' ticks must be positioned between the bars.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for my bad English... the number labels of each ticks must be on the each ticks, like https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram . I'm struggling to make it. I fixed the style of bars. https://jsfiddle.net/taichi_jp/t4nqv5eg/